# Problems using strtok() and stringstream

Tags: c++, c, fstream, stringstream, strtok

I've been fiddling with this for a while now, and all it returns is first two numbers in the 'save.rp' file on separate lines,

```
int characterPosition [2] = {0,0};

string convToStr(char *ch)
{
    stringstream ss;
    string res;
    ss << ch;
    ss >> res;
    return res;
}

int convToInt(string ch)
{
    stringstream ss(ch);
    int num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}

void loadSave()
{
    string loadPos;
    ifstream file("save.rp");
    if ((file.is_open())&&(file.good()))
    {
        getline(file,loadPos);
    }
    file.close();

    char str[] = {*loadPos.c_str()};
    char delim[] = "-";
    char *result = NULL;
    result = strtok(str, delim);
    int num = 0;
    while (result != NULL)
    {
        characterPosition[num] = convToInt(convToStr(result));
        cout << characterPosition[num] << endl;
        result = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}
```

the 'save.rp' file looks like this: 400-2000

Its supposed to return each number seperately, 400 and 2000 in this case.

Am I doing something silly here?

Comment: What do you mean looks like this: 400-2000?

Comment: that's what it contains (sorry for being unclear)

Comment: so it contains 2 numbers - 400 & 2000. So what's your question "all it returns is first two numbers". Or do you mean it contains all numbers from 400 to 2000? Is each number on a separate line.

Comment: it only returns 4 and 0, and they're seperate. it's supposed to return 400, then 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
char str[] = {*loadPos.c_str()};
```

is equivalent to

```
char str[] = {'4'};
```

this is obviously not what you want, you want

```
char str[] = "400-2000";
```

so do this

```
char str[500];                  // assuming your line length dont exceed 500
strcpy( str, loadPos.c_str() );
```

Comment: Beat me by that much...  Kinda surprised strtok doesn't do horrible things with that, but maybe he's just lucky. :)

Comment: thanks a bunch! not only did you help me out, but I now know what I did wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
char str[] = {*loadPos.c_str()};
```

`loadPos.cstr()` returns a pointer to "400-2000";
The * dereferences and gives the first char - i.e. '4'.
You initialize str[] with the first char '4'. str is now an array which starts with '4' and god knows what after that. All your operations are done on this.

Change the above line to

```
char str[100];
strcpy(str,loadPos.c_str());
```

And here is how to avoid the strtok and the convToStr

```
int convToInt(string ch)
{
   stringstream ss(ch);
    int num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}

void loadSave()
{
    string loadPos;
    ifstream file("save.rp");
    if ((file.is_open())&&(file.good()))
    {
        getline(file,loadPos);
    }
    file.close();

    stringstream ss(loadPos);
    string token;

    while(getline(ss, token, '-'))
    {
        int r = convToInt(token);
        cout<<r<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: @MichaelB. updated answer to avoid `strtok`. No reason whatsoever to use `strtok` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inf("save.rp");
    int characterPosition [2] = {0,0};
    int num=0;
    string line_buff;
    while(inf.good()){
        getline(inf, line_buff, '-');
        stringstream ss(line_buff);
        ss >> characterPosition[num++];
    }
    cout << characterPosition[0] << ',' << characterPosition[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```